# Editing iOS .plist file in windows Intel XDK

Tags: ios, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm developing hybrid app using Cordova. Recently I build my iOS package using Adobe Phonegap Build, but I changed my environment to Windows version of Intel XDK.

In  made changes to iOS config file (.plist file) using this in config.xml with Phonegap Build:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIBackgroundModes" overwrite="true">
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
</gap:config-file>
```

how I can do this with Intel XDK?

Also I added exact this lines to "intelxdk.config.additions.xml" file and it doesn't work:

```
<platform name="ios">
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIBackgroundModes" overwrite="true">
<array>
  <string>audio</string>
</array>
</config-file>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my "intelxdk.config.additions.xml" file to:

```
<!-- +iOS --><config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIBackgroundModes" overwrite="true">
 <array>
  <string>audio</string>
 </array>
</config-file>
```

and it's working now! :)

Comment: You stumbled across an undocumented feature that is in development. Not sure when it will be complete and documented, but just wanted to let you know to "tread lightly" with your new found directive. :)

Comment: may you explain better ? i tried adding the code , but build fails

Comment: @atrebbi unfortunately there is nothing more that I know, I just added this into that file and it just works.
after lots of struggling with XDK and other platforms I decided to use OS X (on VM) and use xcode to build for iOS